# Doubts about Manipulation of Layers

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

I'm working with OpenLayers, I created a new plugin to perform a selection feature.
But every event I perform in my plugin button it creates a new layers. (Attached is a print).

Of the attempts that tried to make the removal of the layer were:

```
map.layers.remove (0);
map.layers.length;
map.layers.remove;
```

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't work directly with properties that have get/set method.

For layer manipulation the Map class has getLayer, setLayer and removeLayer methods: http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.getLayer

Try to use them instead.